# Computing the sum of the first n numbers in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun sum(n)
  (cond
    ((= n 0) 0)
    ((= n 1) 1)
    (T (+ n sum (- n 1)))))
```

If I call `(sum 4)` it should show 10 but it gives me an error : Variable SUM has no value

Comment: try replacing sum ( -n 1) with (sum (-n 1))

Comment: `sum` in your function is a variable. You might want to call the function `sum`? Think about using the Lisp syntax for calling functions...

Comment: On another note, what happens if you call `(sum -1)`? ;-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a small typographical error (`sum (- n 1)` instead of `(sum (- n 1))`), and the content of the question isn't likely to help future users with the same problem find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Common Lisp is a Lisp-2, which means that variables and functions are in distinct namespaces.

There is a *function* `sum`, but there is no *variable* `sum`, at the point where you're using it as a variable: `(+ n sum (- n 1))`.

Your intention may have been to write `(+ n (sum (- n 1)))` instead, calling the function `sum` recursively:

```
(defun sum (n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 0)
        ((= n 1) 1)
        (T (+ n (sum (- n 1))))))
```

(If you wanted to refer to the function `sum` as a value, e.g. to pass it to another function, you would write `#'sum`.)

Comment: Why 2 base cases? `(defun sum (n) (if (= n 0) 0 (+ n (sum (- n 1)))))` should do.

Comment: @uselpa Sure, I was just making an exact copy of the asker's code apart from fixing formatting and the issue they were asking about.

Comment: The question was more to the OP, although you could have suggested it too imo.